# Basic R Program (Generate Histogram, Measures of Central Tendency, etc)

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I am writing this code for my probability/statistics class. Keep in mind that I have little knowledge of R. The code I have come up with is generating a few errors that I cannot seem to deal with. First, here is the code I have come up with:

```
filename <- "C://Users//Colin//Desktop//sunspots.txt"
data <- read.table(filename)
colnames(data) <- c("x", "id")

#Questions 1 and 2

mean(data$id)
var(data$id)
summary(data$id)
hist(data$id)

#partial answer to Questions 3 and 4
p <- numeric()

for (i in 1:10000){
s <- data[sample(1:1053,10,replace=FALSE),]
x <- s$id
y[i] <- mean(x)
p[i] <- y[i]
assign(paste("sample",i,sep=""),s)
assign(paste("mean",i,sep=""),y)
}
```

Now, I will post a sample of the data set I am using (it is too big to post the entire thing, I will post it in code tags:

```
"x" "id"
"1" 33
"2" 81
"3" 7
```

This is the exact format of my data set, which is saved as a .txt file. The first error I get is: 
**"Warning message:
In mean.default(data$id) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"**
This is puzzling to me, because I am getting a result for the variance. I am also getting the following error: 
**"Error in hist.default(data$id) : 'x' must be numeric"**
Finally, I am getting this error message:
**"Error in y[i] <- mean(x) : object 'y' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"**
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been trying to fix this code for about an hour now and seem to have made no progress. Thanks.

Comment: The problem:
1. Obtain the sample mean x and sample variance s2
 of the sunspots data.
2. Provide a histogram of the data.
3. For 10000 replications, randomly sample n sunspots observations from the given
dataset. For each replication, obtain the sample mean. That is, you will have 10000
sample means. Compute the sample variance of these sample means.
4. Repeat the above process with n=10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, and 100.
5. Obtain juxtaposed plots of the histograms of the means corresponding to n=10 and
n=100.
6. Plot the variances as the function of n. What are your observations?

Comment: I understand. However, I am getting a result for variance with no error, so why would I then get an error for mean?

Comment: This shows what happens when you have a character vector and you try to compute mean and var - just copy and paste: `x_char <- as.character(1:10); mean(x_char); var(x_char)`. You get a variance but not a mean. Typing `mean.default` in R shows you that there is a check to see if the argument is not numeric. Typing `var` though shows that it only checks if the argument is an atomic vector - not necessarily numeric.

Comment: Thank you. I am still a little bit confused though: the data in my "id" column is numeric, so is there perhaps something wrong with the syntax I am using?

Comment: Add the output of `str(data)` to your post. Also, what is that `y` doing there all by itself? That's the source of your other error.

Comment: 'data.frame':   1054 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x : Factor w/ 1054 levels "1","10","100",..: 1054 1 166 277 388 499 610 721 832 943 ...
$ id: Factor w/ 153 levels "0","1","10","100",..: 153 80 133 120 85 18 145 56 67 4 ...
You are referring to the 'y' inside of the 'for' loop?

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. This is probably a silly question, but the fact that I have quotes around id wouldn't mess anything up, would it?

Comment: adding "header = true" seemed to solve most of the problems, I am now actually generating a histogram and getting reasonable values for the data summary. I am however still getting the object 'y' not found error...

Comment: That's because `y` isn't initialised/defined in your loop. Perhaps get rid of the `p` and use `y` instead - you're not using `p` anywhere anyhow... So put `y <- numeric()`. That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe/hope I will be able to figure out the rest of the problem :D

Comment: One last question, should I use both 
    p <- numeric
and
    y <-numeric
since the p was being used inside of my for loop?

Comment: You don't really do anything with `p`, do you? So get rid of it. Good luck.